# How to do this by using css3

Tags: css

How can I replicate [this image](http://www.mediafire.com/i/?zyygykbnpela1ya) using CSS?
Note: image should be in img tag, not as background

Comment: what are you asking here and how is it related to css3 ?

Comment: as far i can tell, he wants to replicate the image in html using css3.

Answer (score 4):

I created 2 versions.

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/B82AX/5/

Comment: Hi Gecko Tang, Tqs for giving this css3 code, this exapmle useful to me

Comment: please mark this answer as the correct one. give credit where is due :)

Answer (score 2):

Really quick answer with mostly static heights etc

http://jsfiddle.net/9xvUF/3/

You put the image you want as a background image

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to pull this off though

Good luck

Comment: Hi, Tqs for giving this css3 information, but i need image should be <img> tag not as background, because i am using images as dynamic,

Comment: You can add the background image to the style attribute of the div. like i said there SHOULD be better way out there. this is just a quick hack :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you what i mean by placing in the style attribute. it works very well considering

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<img style='border-radius:200px;' width='200' height='200' src="http://www.tuswallpapersgratis.com/images/wallpapers/leon1-600553.jpeg" alt=''/>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/B82AX/

Answer (score 0):

if what your looking for it how to make a round image, heres an example:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-image-styles